# Неправильно выполняются операции калькулятора

Tags: java, swing, button, калькулятор

Сделано в точности по книге Файна, но при операциях число суммирует/отнимает само себя или делится/умножается само на себя. Понимаю, почему оно работает неправильно, но не знаю, как исправить. Код из рабочего класса (графический прописан отдельно и просто вызывает данные команды):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Dwizhok implements ActionListener {

    Main parent;

char selectedAction =' ';
double currentResult = 0;

Dwizhok(Main parent){

    this.parent = parent;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton clickButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
    String dispFieldText = parent.okno.getText();
    double displayValue = 0;

    if (!"".equals(dispFieldText)) {

        displayValue = Double.parseDouble(dispFieldText);
    }

    Object src = e.getSource();

    if (src == parent.butPlus) {

        selectedAction = '+';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.okno.setText("");

    } else if (src == parent.butMinus) {

        selectedAction = '-';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.okno.setText("");

    } else if (src == parent.butUmnozh) {

        selectedAction = '*';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.okno.setText("");
    } else if (src == parent.butPodel) {

        selectedAction = '/';
        currentResult = displayValue;
        parent.okno.setText("");
    } else if (src == parent.butRawno);

    if (selectedAction == '+') {

        currentResult += displayValue;
        parent.okno.setText("" + currentResult);

    } else if (selectedAction == '-') {
        currentResult -= displayValue;
        parent.okno.setText("" + currentResult);

    } else if (selectedAction == '*') {

        currentResult *= displayValue;
        parent.okno.setText("" + currentResult);

    } else if (selectedAction == '/') {

        currentResult /= displayValue;
        parent.okno.setText("" + currentResult);

    } else {
        String clickedButtonLabel = clickButton.getText();
        parent.okno.setText(dispFieldText + clickedButtonLabel);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать почему оно работает не правильно? Точнее ваше понимание "Понимаю, почему оно работает неправильно"

Comment: Как мне кажется, оно в этих операциях как раз и добавляет само себя " currentResult += displayValue;".

Comment: Абсолютно верно Вам кажется вы вот здесь `currentResult = displayValue;` их уравниваете вместо того чтобы хранить уже известное значение и значение только введенное; Уберите эти строки по идее должно быть как нужно

Comment: Да нет. Все равно ничего не происходит. Как сделать так, чтобы операции выполнялись?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте мой код, вдруг сработает?

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.*;

public class Calculator implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("JCalculator");
    private JTextField resultField;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton a0Button;
    private JButton a1Button;
    private JButton a2Button;
    private JButton a3Button;
    private JButton a4Button;
    private JButton a5Button;
    private JButton a6Button;
    private JButton a7Button;
    private JButton a8Button;
    private JButton a9Button;
    private JButton plusButton;
    private JButton equalsButton;
    private JButton minusButton;
    private JButton multiplyButton;
    private JButton divideButton;
    private double num1, res = 0;
    private String operation;
    private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[]{a0Button, a1Button, a2Button, a3Button, a4Button, a5Button, a6Button, a7Button, a8Button, a9Button};

    Calculator() {
        jFrame.setContentPane(panel);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        for (JButton button: buttons) {
            button.addActionListener(this);
        }
        plusButton.addActionListener(this);
        minusButton.addActionListener(this);
        multiplyButton.addActionListener(this);
        divideButton.addActionListener(this);
        equalsButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int i = 0;
        for (JButton button: buttons) {
            if (e.getSource() == button) {
                if (res == 0) {
                    resultField.setText(giveNewString(resultField, i));
                } else {
                    res = 0;
                    resultField.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (e.getSource() == plusButton) {
            num1 = resultField.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(resultField.getText());
            operation = "+";
            resultField.setText("");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == minusButton) {
            num1 = resultField.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(resultField.getText());
            operation = "-";
            resultField.setText("");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == multiplyButton) {
            num1 = resultField.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(resultField.getText());
            operation = "*";
            resultField.setText("");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == divideButton) {
            num1 = resultField.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(resultField.getText());
            operation = "/";
            resultField.setText("");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == equalsButton) {
            double num2;
            try {
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(resultField.getText());
                switch (operation) {
                    case "+":                        
                        res = num1 + num2;
                        resultField.setText(Double.toString(res));
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        res = num1 - num2;
                        resultField.setText(Double.toString(res));
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        res = num1*num2;
                        resultField.setText(Double.toString(res));
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        try {
                            res = num1/num2;
                            resultField.setText(Double.toString(res));
                        } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {      //execute if num2 == 0
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jFrame, "You tried to divide by zero", "Error",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            resultField.setText("");
                        }
                        break;
                        default:        //execute if operation == ""
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jFrame, "You must enter two numbers, entered one", "Error",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            resultField.setText("");
                            break;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {        //execute if num2 can't be parse to int
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jFrame, "You must enter two numbers, entered one", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                resultField.setText("");
            }
            num1 = 0;
            operation = "";
        }
    }
    private String giveNewString(JTextField textField, int number) {
        return textField.getText() + number;
    }
}
```